# How to fill field data by checking condition in crystal report?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

Consider the below records which retrieved from database,

**My xsd datatable fields are**,

```
categoryName
categoryType
prize
```

**Datatable records**

```
category name - category type - prize
--------------------------------------
c1            - 1             - 10
c2            - 1             - 20
c3            - 2             - 10
c4            - 2             - 10
c5            - 1             - 30
c6            - 2             - 30
c7            - 1             - 10
c7            - 2             - 10
```

**Expected report output to be in report as given below**,

### summary of category

```
category name - pize    |     category name - prize
c1            - 10      |     c3            - 10
c2            - 20      |     c4            - 10
c5            - 30      |     c6            - 30
c7            - 10      |     c7            - 10
                        |
Total type1             |  Total type2
prize         - 70      |  prize            - 60


Grand total   - 130
```

please help anyone how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create 2 subreports. Put them side-by-side outside the details section. For example, in the page header. Make the layout (category name and prize columns).
2. Change the subreport links. The one to the left shall be filtered by type1. The one to the right shall be filtered by type2.
3. In another section below (may be the page footer), put the two running total fields side-by-side. One of them shall summarize by type1 and the other by type2.
4. Add another section below and put the grand total.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Is it possible to make in single sub report by giving condition?

Comment: I do not know how to do that without using 2 sub reports, since i understand you want to put them side by side. Maybe if there is a column break option in Crystal Reports, but i have no acknowledge of that.

Answer (score 0):

No need of sub report instead use the cross tab in main report and take first column as type and second as category and for summation part take price you will get required output